# SUM of a secondSELECT statement - PHP - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, limit, group-concat

I have the following query which works... but I need some changes:

```
SELECT
    p.pid,
    p.name,   
    GROUP_CONCAT( gC.leaguepoints ORDER BY leaguepoints DESC ) AS leaguepoints        
FROM
    golf_player p
LEFT JOIN
    golf_card gC ON
    p.pid = gC.pid
GROUP BY
    p.pid
ORDER BY
    p.name
DESC
```

What I really want is another property returned called totalleaguepoints which is a SUM of the most recent 20 league points in my table.

How do I add a limit to a group_concat?

It might be something like this?

```
 SELECT                
      p.pid,
      p.name,   
      GROUP_CONCAT( gC.leaguepoints ORDER BY leaguepoints DESC ) AS leaguepoints, 
      SUM(  
        SELECT 
          gC2.leaguepoints
        FROM
          golf_card gC2
        WHERE 
          gC2.pid = p.pid
        ORDER BY
          leaguepoints
          DESC
        LIMIT 20           
      ) AS totalleaguepoints
  FROM
    golf_player p
  LEFT JOIN
    golf_card gC ON
    p.pid = gC.pid
  GROUP BY
    p.pid
  ORDER BY
    p.name
    DESC
```

P.S, the above query does not run

Comment: `How do I add a limit to a group_concat?` you don't create a filter in the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want just the top 20 league points for each player in the group_concat as well as the sum?

If so maybe use user variables:-

```
SELECT                
    p.pid,
    p.name,   
    GROUP_CONCAT( gC.leaguepoints ORDER BY leaguepoints DESC ) AS leaguepoints, 
    SUM(gC.leaguepoints) AS totalleaguepoints
FROM golf_player p
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT pid, leaguepoints, @Sequence:=IF(@PrevPid = pid, @Sequence + 1, 0) AS aSequence, @PrevPid := pid
    FROM
    (
        SELECT pid, leaguepoints
        FROM golf_card 
        ORDER BY pid, leaguepoints DESC
    ) Sub1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @PrevPid := 0, @Sequence := 0) Sub2
) gC
ON p.pid = gC.pid AND aSequence < 20
GROUP BY p.pid
ORDER BY p.name DESC
```

Comment: What about if I got all players, then did a loop in PHP through my players and got their league numbers.. Is this at all any more stressfull than doing the one query? Is that reasonable?

Comment: Multiple queries are generally slow. The above query should be reasonably efficient (although not tested)

Comment: this is more tricky than it seems :-) quite good query, but it's not working yet ;) http://pastebin.com/YYAQPnAw

Comment: Arghh, this is gnna take me a while to comprehend. these variables are new to me :'(

Comment: @DanFromGermany - thanks for sorting out the test db. Changed it from <=20 to <20 to sort the issue.

Comment: It gets a list of the records ordered by the pid then the league points descending. Once it has that it uses a user variable to get a sequence. When the pid changes it sets the sequence back to 0. Hence you get all the records each with a sequence which starts at 0 and goes increases by 1 for each leaguepoint . Then it just selects the items from that where the sequence number is less than 20.

Comment: I have a prefix `test_` messed a little in the sql export.
Using your query it still doesn't stop at 20 / each player for me :S

Comment: @DanFromGermany - I used your test data (and added some more to make one well over 20 entries) and it did stop at 20. See this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a8b3/1

Comment: Thx for the fiddle. I quit this thread now not to end in a discussion, I asked a new question of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547108/different-results-in-sqlfiddle-com-5-5-30-and-mariadb-5-5-31