# Different results in sqlfiddle.com 5.5.30 and MariaDB 5.5.31

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sqlfiddle

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a8b3/1

Taking the structure and data and query from the fiddle,
importing into my MariaDB 5.5.31, I get different results:

sqlfiddle

```
PID  NAME       LEAGUEPOINTS        TOTALLEAGUEPOINTS
2   Peter   16,13,9,4,2            44
1   Daniel  3425,543,234,43,29,22,21,21,19,17,13,12,12,12,11,9,9,9,8,7      4476
```

mariadb

```
pid  name    leaguepoints       totalleaguepoints   
2   Peter   16,13,9,4,2             44
1   Daniel  3425,543,234,43,29,22,21,21,19,17,13,12,12,12,11,9,9,9,8,7,7,6,5,5,4,4,4,3,3,2,1    4520
```

Query:

```
SELECT                
    p.pid,
    p.name,   
    GROUP_CONCAT( gC.leaguepoints ORDER BY leaguepoints DESC ) AS leaguepoints, 
    SUM(gC.leaguepoints) AS totalleaguepoints
FROM test_golf_player p
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT pid, leaguepoints, @Sequence:=IF(@PrevPid = pid, @Sequence + 1, 0) AS aSequence, @PrevPid := pid
    FROM
    (
        SELECT pid, leaguepoints
        FROM test_golf_card 
        ORDER BY pid, leaguepoints DESC
    ) Sub1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @PrevPid := 0, @Sequence := 0) Sub2
) gC
ON p.pid = gC.pid AND aSequence < 20
GROUP BY p.pid
ORDER BY p.name DESC
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afraid I don't have MariaDB to hand, but could you try the following just to see how the user variables are output:-

```
SELECT  *
FROM test_golf_player p
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT pid, leaguepoints, @Sequence:=IF(@PrevPid = pid, @Sequence + 1, 0) AS aSequence, @PrevPid := pid
    FROM
    (
        SELECT pid, leaguepoints
        FROM test_golf_card 
        ORDER BY pid, leaguepoints DESC
    ) Sub1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @PrevPid := 0, @Sequence := 0) Sub2
) gC
ON p.pid = gC.pid 
ORDER BY p.name DESC
```

EDIT - Doing a bit of investigation looking at your results it seems that MariaDB has ignored the ORDER BY in the sub query. Hence the sequence number is in a random order, and also resets when the pid changes (which it does randomly due to the order not being fixed). Bit of a google and it seems this is a deliberate feature of MariaDB. The SQL standard defines a table as an unordered set of rows, and a sub select is treated as a table hence the order by is ignored - https://kb.askmonty.org/en/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/ .

It is a bit of a disadvantage. Not sure there is a work around as I can't think of one at the moment. For the original problem that this was to deal with I think it would be necessary to use correlated sub selects which would probably not be efficient.

Comment: Looking at those results I think that Maria may have ignored the ORDER BY clause in the inner sub select. Hence the sequence number is in a random order, and also resets when the pid changes (which it does random due to the order not being fixed).

Comment: Seems this is a deliberate feature of MariaDB. The SQL standard defines a table as an unordered set of rows, and a sub select is treated as a table hence the order by is ignored - https://kb.askmonty.org/en/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/

Comment: thx for the research. interesting! this is a disadvantage, isnt it? You think there's any workaround? I'm not sure, I didnt make use of `ORDER BY` in subquery yet.

Comment: It is a bit of a disadvantage. Not sure there is a work around as I can't think of one at the moment. For the original problem that this was to deal with I think it would be necessary to use correlated sub selects which would probably not be efficient.

Comment: Well I can live with that for now but I really prefere MariaDB/XtraDB over native MySQL. If you edit your answer with the comment above I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: Edited to highlight the issue